# How can I update the dataset in my vb.net 2012 report after changing a table structure?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have created a report in vb 2012 and it was very involved and would prefer not to re-do it.  My problem is that I have made a small change to a table's structure.  I've updated the table adapter in visual studio but in my report, it still shows the older version of the table adapter before I made the changes.  I cant seem to find a way to update the dataset without starting over completely with my report.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To refresh the fields for a specific dataset**

1. In the Report Data pane, right-click the dataset, and then click
   Dataset Properties.

   **Note:**
   If the Report Data pane is not visible, on the View menu, click Report Data. If the pane
   opens as a floating window, you can dock it.
2. In the Query pane, type the query.
3. Click Refresh Fields.
4. Click OK.

In the Report Data pane, expand the dataset node to view the currently defined field collection.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365160(v=sql.100).aspx